# ClassNotFoundException : While accessing the Google Analytics API v4

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to fetch some data from Google Analytics using Google Analytics reporting v4 API.
I am using maven so included all the 9 modules in maven dependency.

However while running the sample java code from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError. On debugging further the actual line which was failing is
**Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory();**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/async/NonBlockingJsonParser
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils$JsonFactoryInstanceHolder.<clinit>(Utils.java:44)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory(Utils.java:36)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:232)
    at com.dropbox.aem.common.services.GoogleAnalyticsReporting.initializeAnalyticsReporting(GoogleAnalyticsReporting.java:58)
    at com.dropbox.aem.common.services.GoogleAnalyticsReporting.main(GoogleAnalyticsReporting.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.async.NonBlockingJsonParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Jackson core. From here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Comment: After adding jackson-core i am not getting this error anymore but now i am having another error like 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J
 at com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:227)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:136).  

I added guava (com.google.guava) dependency but no luck.